# CSV Writer writing duplicate rows

Tags: python, csv

I am new to programming and currently trying to parse NMAP XML to CSV.
When i open the CSV file i see that there is more rows than it should of been.

Anyone would be able to tell me what I did wrong with the code below?

```
from libnmap.parser import NmapParser
import os
import csv

report = 'nmap_results.xml'

with open('nmap_results.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    for filename in report:
        nmap_report = NmapParser.parse_fromfile(report)

        for host in nmap_report.hosts:
            row = []
            for hostname in host.hostnames:
                row.append('{}'.format(hostname))

            row.append('{}'.format(host.address))

            for serv in host.services:
                row.append(serv.port)

            writer.writerow(row)
```

Here is the out of CSV:

```
yahoo.com,media-router-fp1.prod1.media.vip.gq1.yahoo.com,98.137.246.7,53,80,443
red.com,server-13-249-188-122.bos50.r.cloudfront.net,13.249.188.122,53,80,443
google.com,172.18.128.1,53,80,443
cnn.com,151.101.1.67,53
yahoo.com,media-router-fp1.prod1.media.vip.gq1.yahoo.com,98.137.246.7,53,80,443
red.com,server-13-249-188-122.bos50.r.cloudfront.net,13.249.188.122,53,80,443
google.com,172.18.128.1,53,80,443
cnn.com,151.101.1.67,53
yahoo.com,media-router-fp1.prod1.media.vip.gq1.yahoo.com,98.137.246.7,53,80,443
red.com,server-13-249-188-122.bos50.r.cloudfront.net,13.249.188.122,53,80,443
google.com,172.18.128.1,53,80,443
```

Comment: you may be missing an import... not sure what `NmapParser is`. Also you are iterating over a string. `report` is a string. so your code is saying in english: `for each character in this string, do this task` Do you mean to put `report` in a list?

Comment: Sorry, the import is thee I just edit my original question.

NmapParser is from libnmap https://libnmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I would just like to save the Nmap result to CSV and this is how I was able to do it for now, but it writes the results multiple times to CSV.

Comment: There is 4 entries for testing purposes.

Comment: right but you're repeating the task many times, to @MattR point. You are iterating over `report` which is a string and for each character of this string you are performing the function of writing out to a file. seems like you don't need to iterate over `report` and can just scrap that whole `for-loop` to be honest.

Comment: All i see is `for filename in report:` but no future reference to filename within the loop (instead you refer to report on the next line).

Comment: Good bit of practice here, would be to try stepping through this in a debugger. If your editor isn't set up for breakpoints you can write `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` somewhere at the start of your code, and when you run it you'll be able to step through line by line. You should be able to find the issue then.

Comment: Thank you @aws_apprentice I removed the first for loop and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above. It looks lik you have too many loops. `report` is your xml. How many times does each filename appear in `nmap_results.xml`? Becuase your first loop says

```
for filename in report
```

Well if a certain `filename` like `file_A.blah` appears more then once in `nmap_results.xml`, then you will run `NmapParser.parse_fromfile(report)` on that report name multiple times.

I'm assuming that `nmap_report` isa nested structure, like a JSON, or another XML

```
{hosts: [ {hostnames: [ftw, fml],
           address  : www.aol.com,
           services : [ {port: 10 },
                        {port: 20 } ] },

          {hostnames: [wtf, wow],
           address  : www.yahoo.com,
           services : [ {port: 31 },
                        {port: 41 } ] },

          {hostnames: [lol, log]
           address  : www.msn.com,
           services : [ {port: 52 },
                        {port: 62 } ] },

          {hostnames: [omg, okc],
           address  : www.url.com,
           services : [ {port: 404 }
                        {port: 88 } ] },
        ] }
```

Above, is my imagined structure of `nmap_report`
- `nmap_report.hosts` is a List with 4 items. Thus `for x in blah.hosts` is *kind of* valid
- each item (call it a `host`) is Dictionary with keys `hostnames`, `address`, `services`

I'm pretending you can call a Python Dictionary with "dot" notation. In any case. The structure works. So, by your loop, we have:

````
    for host in nmap_report.hosts:
        row = []
        for hostname in host.hostnames:
            row.append('{}'.format(hostname))

        row.append('{}'.format(host.address))

        for serv in host.services:
            row.append(serv.port)

        writer.writerow(row)``` <--- by the way, this is a typo right? remove these '''
````

row 1 `[] --> [ftw, fml]  --> [ftw, fml, www.aol.com]  --> [ftw, fml, www.aol.com, 10, 20]`
row 2 `[] --> [wtf, wow]`  same pattern
row 3 `[] --> [lol, log]`  same pattern
row 4 `[] --> [omg, okc]`  same pattern

You should check if `writer.writerow(row)` adds a new line also, again check that those three back ticks (`) are removed from this line.

Based on the example that I deduced from your structure, the reason you have duplicates is because `for filename in report:` is using the same filename multiple times.

Your filenames from `report = 'nmap_results.xml'` are not unique.

Comment: The OP has already figured-out how to solve their problem — see the last comment under their question.